# Import Loop When Using Delegate Both Ways?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops, import, delegates

In my app I have found myself needing to use a delegate both to and from my view controller.

So view controller 1 delegate is used in view controller 2 and view controller 2 delegate is used in view controller 1.

To implement a delegate I need to import the header file, inside the other view controllers header file. However this causes an import loop, so how can I get around this if I want to send info both ways?

Thanks.

Comment: just create a "Protocol Header File" (XCode -> File -> New -> File -> iOS -> Cocoa Touch -> Objective-C protocol), import this file in your needed view controllers and view header files.

Comment: So just have a header file with all of my protocols in? Then import that single header where needed?

Comment: yes, that is the correct solution or you can declare a @protocol YourProtocolName; in the Header files (.h) and include the necessary Protocol in the .m file

Comment: Brilliant, that was simple and worked a charm. Thanks.